# Convert 1-100 to another value set

Tags: javascript, math, numbers

Using JavaScript, I wish to convert a value between 1-100 to a corresponding value set between 1000-150000. What is the best approach for this? Comparing and multiplying / dividing array values, or is there an easier way?

Comment: As an example, how do you plan to convert `42`?

Comment: `var fortytwo = Infinity;`

Comment: Why would you convert 42? It is already the correct answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you would want to obtain value for 42 in value set {1000-150000}, you would need to use this formula:

```
((150000-1000)/100*42)+1000
```

Thus simpliying with:

```
f(x) = (1490*x)+1000
```

So, `f(0) = 1000` , `f(100) = 150000` and `f(50) = 75500`.

Using javascript:

```
function getCorrespondingValue( myValue){
     return (1490 * myValue) + 1000;
}
```

Comment: Oh dear... math was never my favorite subject in college. Not sure how to implement this into a function. How do you come to the conclusion of using number 1490?

Comment: @StaffanEstberg He already basically has it in the form of a function. `function converter(x) { return (1490*x)+1000; }`

Comment: Oh, it was that simple to add. Guys, THANKS!

Comment: I'm curious though how you came up with the number, since I have another set of numbers that need to be converted as well...

Comment: @StaffanEstberg Look at the simplification. He simplifies it from `((150000-1000)/100*x)+1000` to `(1490*x)+1000`. Just plug in the numbers you're using and simplify

Comment: Simple slope formula. Difference in Y's divided by difference in X's. He took the two pairs [0, 1000] and [100, 150000], found the slope to be (150000-1000)/100 = 1490. Which is what m is in the slope formula `y = mx + b` Then to find the y-intercept (b), he just plugged in one set of numbers 1000 = 1490*0 + b, b = 1000. Thus you get `y = 1490x + 1000`

Comment: I just got smarter today. Thanks!